# Python - Execute command line function on every file in a directory?

Tags: python, mysql, command-line, subprocess, rename

I have a directory of CSV files that I want to import into MySQL. There are about 100 files, and doing a manual import is painful.

My command line is this:

```
mysqlimport -u root -ppassword --local --fields-terminated-by="|" data PUBACC_FR.dat
```

The files are all of type `XX.dat`, i.e. `AC.dat`, `CP.dat`, etc. I actually rename them first before processing them (via `rename 's/^/PUBACC_/' *.dat`). Ideally I'd like to be able to accomplish both tasks in one script: Rename the files, then run the command.

From what I've found reading, something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith("dat"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
```

Can anyone help me get started with a script that will accomplish this, please? Read the file names, rename them, then for each one run the `mysqlimport` command?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I wouldn't do both tasks in the same script.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do that in Python ? You can simply run `ls *dat|xargs -n 1  mysqlimport -u root -ppassword --local --fields-terminated-by="|" data` in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose something like the python code below could be used:

```
import subprocess
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in os.listdir("."):
        if (f.endswith(".dat")):
            subprocess.call("echo %s" % f, shell=True)
```

Obviously, you should change the command from echo to your command instead.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html for more details of using subprocess, or see the possible duplicate.